# Failed to insert data in database with PreparedStatement with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, prepared-statement, forms, http-post

I'm trying to insert data into database using PreparedStatement based on form input. The program follows normal flow when user clicks "submit" on the checkout page (checkout.jsp) the form redirect him to the confirmation.jsp as wanted but no data gets inserted. When user submit forms, the program seems to ignore the PreparedStatement and only notices the userPath. I wonder what could be the cause of this behavior? No error gets printed.

Servlet.java

```
        } else if (userPath.equals("/purchase")) {

       String OD = request.getParameter("OD");    
          String FN = request.getParameter("FN");  
          String LN = request.getParameter("LN");  
          String PN = request.getParameter("PN");  
          String EM = request.getParameter("EM");  
          String A1 = request.getParameter("A1");  
          String A2 = request.getParameter("A2");  
          String CT = request.getParameter("CT");  
          String SPR = request.getParameter("SPR");  
          String PZC = request.getParameter("PZC");  
          String CTRY = request.getParameter("CTRY");  
          String referenceNumber = request.getParameter("referenceNumber");  
          String status = request.getParameter("status");  
          String queue = request.getParameter("queue");  
          String cart_total = request.getParameter("cart_total");  
          String order_details = request.getParameter("order_details");  
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/application?user=root&password=12345");
     PreparedStatement pst;
     pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert into customer_order(date_created, first_name,last_name,phone,email,address_1,address_2,city,State_Province_Region,Postal_Zip_Code,country,referenceNumber,status,queue,cart_total,order_details) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     //When concating strings you should do something like st = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into student values ('" + userid + "','"+pw+"')"); but the right way is
     //st = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into student values (1,2)");
       pst.setString(1,OD);
                    pst.setString(2,FN);
                    pst.setString(3,LN);
                    pst.setString(4,PN);
                    pst.setString(5,EM);
                    pst.setString(6,A1);
                    pst.setString(7,A2);
                    pst.setString(8,CT);
                    pst.setString(9,SPR);
                    pst.setString(10,PZC);
                    pst.setString(11,CTRY);
                    pst.setString(12,referenceNumber);
                    pst.setString(13,status);
                    pst.setString(14,queue);
                    pst.setString(15,cart_total);
                    pst.setString(16,order_details);

     pst.executeUpdate();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
     //print a message or something
}finally{
           Connection connection = null;
     if (connection!=null){
               try {
                   connection.close();
               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(ControllerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
     }
}
            userPath = "/confirmation";
        }
```

Checkout.jsp

```
<form  id="shipping_form"  method="post" action="purchase" name="checkout">

                                <label for="date" class="shp_label">Order Date </label>
                                <input id="date" name="OD" type="text" class="shp_ipt" value="<%= new java.util.Date()%>" readonly>

                                <label for="fname" class="shp_label">First Name   </label>
                                <input id="fname" name="FN" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>


                                <label for="lname" class="shp_label">Last Name   </label>
                                <input id="lname" name="LN" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>

                                <label for="phone" class="shp_label"> Phone  </label>
                                <input id="phone" name="PN" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>

                                <label for="email" class="shp_label"> Email   </label>
                                <input id="email" name="EM"  type="email" class="shp_ipt" required>

                                <label for="add1" class="shp_label"> Address 1  </label>
                                <input id="add1" name="A1" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>


                                <label for="add2" class="shp_label"> Address 2   </label>
                                <input id="add2" name="A2" type="text" class="shp_ipt">

                                <label for="city" class="shp_label"> City   </label>
                                <input id="city" name="CT"  type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>


                                <label for="spr" class="shp_label"> Region  </label>
                                <input id="spr" name="SPR" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>


                                <label for="pzc" class="shp_label"> Zip / Code </label>
                                <input id="pzc" name="PZC" type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>

                                <label for="country" class="shp_label"> Country </label>
                                <input id="country"name="CTRY"  type="text" class="shp_ipt" required>


<input type="hidden" name="referenceNumber" value="<%=System.currentTimeMillis()%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="staus" value="Pending" />
<input type="hidden" name="queue" value="This information will be updated soon." />
<input type="hidden" class="cartTotal"  style="border:none; background:transparent;" name="cart_total" readonly type="text" value="${cart.total}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="order_details" value="Your order is being processed." />                                


<input class="submit_button button" name="submit" value="Ship Me!" type="submit">



                            </form>
```

Comment: How do you know that the block of code in the `else-if` is executing?

Comment: @fdsa: Thanks for your reply. Because on the checkout page, when I fill up the form and click on submit, the form is being sent to the confirmation page which tells me that part of the `else-if` is being executed, no `:S`? I get same result by removing everything in-between the `else-if`. It behaves just as if there is no `PreparedStatement` at all. It knows the path but have no clue that the query exists, if that make sense. I have just rewrote a new PreparedStatement from scratch. I will update the OP.

Comment: make a separate JSP to check that connection is properly obtain or not ?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Check again form is submitting or not or check in your database again or print out the statement inside try block to just check code is being executed or not. .

Answer (score 0):

If you have no error found then you can change some code in preparedStatement . Like this -

pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert into customer_order values('"+FN+"', '"+LN+"',.........) ");

And one think remember that after PreparedStatement it is must be perform execute() method , by PreparedStatement's object . Like this -
pst.execute();